# How to securely disconnect all clients and DataChannels in Indy10 IdFtpServer

Tags: delphi, ftp, indy, ftp-server

I'm developing a ftp server (just now using Delphi XE 6 and Indy 10), all fine except at the moment of close the application. Is some client's connected but not downloading/uploading the app finish fine, but if i have some data channels opened (some clients downloading/uploading files) then the app Crash (laun some Access Violation and Freeze). So the question is: How to securely Disconnect all clients (sending some type of notification to all clients that server goes offline with status 421) and then securely kill all data channels. Is good to see how to securely close SSLConnections instances too (i'm using IdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL to SSL connections).

Here is the code i have at the moment:

```
procedure TfrmMain.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

  //TThread.Synchronize
  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    var
      vX, vCount: Integer;
      vProcContext: TIdFTPServerContext;
    begin
      with FTPServer.Contexts.LockList Do
      try
        try
          vCount := Count;
          Log('Clients connected: ' + IntToStr(vCount));
          for vX := vCount - 1 downto 0 do
          begin
            vProcContext := Items[vX];
            //vProcContext := TIdFTPServerContext(Items[vX]);
            Assert(vProcContext is TIdFTPServerContext);
            if vProcContext = nil then
                 Continue;
            //I add this later but don't work.
            vProcContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteBufferClear;
            vProcContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
            vProcContext.Connection.IOHandler.Close;
            if vProcContext.Connection.Connected then
               vProcContext.Connection.Disconnect;
            vProcContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('421 Server is going offline');
            vProcContext.Connection.Disconnect;

            //TIdDataChannelAccess(vProcContext.DataChannel).FDataChannel.Disconnect;
            vProcContext.KillDataChannel;
            TIdYarnOfThread(vProcContext.Yarn).Thread.Terminate;
          end;
        except
          on e : Exception do
          begin
            Log('Error en btn: ' + e.Message);
            raise;
          end;
        end;
      finally
        FTPServer.Contexts.UnlockList;
      end;
    end
  );

 IdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL.Shutdown;
 IdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL.Destroy;
 FTPServer.Active := False;

end;
```

This is my Log procedure:

```
procedure TfrmMain.Log(LogText: String; AppendDateTime: Boolean = False);
begin
  //TThread.Synchronize
  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      logMemo.Lines.Add('> ' + LogText);
    end
  );
end;
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for my poor english :( !

Comment: `TIdFTPServer` already disconnects all clients and transfers in progress when deactivating the server. You don't have to do anything extra for that. Just set `Active=False` and let `TIdFTPServer` handle everything for you. If you are getting AVs or freezes then either you are not using `TIdFTPServer` correctly (what does the rest of your code look like?), or you found a bug. Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces the issue. And what platform are you targeting?

Comment: Also FYI, calling `TThread.Queue()` or `TThread.Synchronize()` in the main UI thread (like in a button `OnClick` event) is useless. The specified procedure is called immediately without any delay. This is documented behavior

Comment: @remy-lebeau this is strange. When i run the app in debug, this show some Access Violation errors, but when i run with no debug, this work well?